# specific user view content of web php

Tags: php, html, web

I have this simple code

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<head>
  <title>WWW</title>
</head>  
<body>  
<?php
  if($_SESSION['login']!=""){
?>
<header>
Welcome admin
</header>
<?php
{ else echo“Only admin can see this page“ } ?>
```

But I dont know how to make only user called "Admin" to view this page and not other users. I have an SQL database of users with nick, password and email.

Comment: Have an `isAdmin` flag in your users table. Store the value in a session when the user logs in and check against it on the admin page. `if ($_SESSION['isAdmin']) { //display }`

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Answering with code for your problem is not possible.

But, some steps as following will work for you:

1) Along with `users` table, add another tables `user_roles` and `roes`

2) In `roes`, fields: id, name (e.g. 1-Admin, 2-User)

3) In `user_roles`, user-role relationship, e.g. 1-1 (Admin user-Admin Role)

4) Now, after session check, find out user's role and then go ahead.

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you, and how do I find out users role with code?

Comment: Search on internet with proper terms :) That is the only solution.